# Copy to clipboard button in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery

Is there any way to create a copy to clipboard button on Safari? This is my code, but it does not work in Safari.

```
<input type="text" id="copy"/>
<button class="copy-button" id="button-copy">Copy</button>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    document.querySelector('#button-copy').addEventListener('click', 
    function(e) {
                $(this).prev().select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: use this $('#copy').select(); at the place of  $(this).prev().select();

Comment: @AnsarHusain thanks but it still does not work. I think maybe the problem is document.execCommand("copy").

Comment: This has nothing to do with magento - should be asked in a javascript/jquery forum.

Comment: @jscar Thanks for your suggestion. But finally, I found the answer by myself. Maybe I should delete this question?

Comment: @Thanh  That's good news. In that case post your answer so others can benefit